# Dynamic programming applied on a recursive algorithm

Tags: java, dynamic-programming

so bellow is my code for an algorithm using recursive calls. I will not explain what the algorithms exactly does, because i do not think that it is important to know for this question. It basically just calculates the amount of valid paths for a given input n. The algorithm has exponential complexity, so it is really slow for bigger n.

With the current algorithm i am only able to calculate n up to 10 in realistic time, but other people working on the same problem told me that it is possible to get up to 200 with the same recursive approach i took by adding in dynamic programming. So i read into dynamic programming a bit and i think i understood what it is supposed to do. It memorizes previous calculations so you do not have to calculate them again, instead you can just take them out of a list or so.

But i do not understand how i am able to apply that for my code, could anyone help me out or atleast give me a hint?

```
public class CalculatePaths {

static private int n;
static private int remainingSteps; // calculates how many steps are left
static private int paths = 0; // calculates how many valid paths there are

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a value for n: ");
    n = scanner.nextInt();
    remainingSteps = 2 * n;

    move(0, 0, 0, 0, remainingSteps);
    System.out.println("There are " + paths + " valid paths for n = " + n);
}

/**
 * Goes through all paths and calculates the amount of valid paths
 * Stops if x or y or negative
 * Stops when all steps were used
 * A valid path has to meet the following conditions: 
 * 1. There arent any remaning steps left
 * 2. The x-coordinate has to be 0
 * 3. The y-coordinate has to be equal to n
 */
public static void move(int xDirection, int yDirection, int parentx, int parenty, int remainingSteps) {

    // calculates the current coorindates with the parent coordinates and the direction coordinates
    parentx = parentx + xDirection;
    parenty = parenty + yDirection;


    if (parentx == 0 && parenty == n && remainingSteps == 0) { 
        paths++;
    }

    // recursive call as long as the coordinates arent negative and there are still remaining steps
    if (remainingSteps > 0 && parentx >= 0 && parenty >= 0) {
        move(1, 0, parentx, parenty, remainingSteps - 1); // goes to the right...
        move(0, 1, parentx, parenty, remainingSteps - 1); // goes up...
        move(0, -1, parentx, parenty, remainingSteps - 1); // goes down...
        move(-1, 1, parentx, parenty, remainingSteps - 1); // diagonal top left...
    }
}
}
```

Comment: How are you marking paths?

Answer (score 0):

you can you use 2D matrix and pass it along your move function. when you are at each cell you make an entry for of the computation for each cell. So when you are in the next cell you can just calculate from the previous cell.
And you have a bug in your recursive move function call it should be.

```
 move(x+1, 0, parentx, parenty, remainingSteps - 1); // goes to the right...
 move(0, y+1, parentx, parenty, remainingSteps - 1); // goes up...
 move(0, y-1, parentx, parenty, remainingSteps - 1); // goes down...
 move(x-1, 0, parentx, parenty, remainingSteps - 1); // diagonal top left...
```

hope this helps, I don't want to write the code for you leave it up to you to figure it out.